# No Desktop appear after logged in using lightdm Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lightdm

Guest Logged in working fine...But When i do logging with my user account..logged in gets successful but after logged in ..nothing appears on desktop except wallpaper of ubuntu.
Facing this problem from so many days.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your terminal or login into tty2 (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and go to home folder by using command `cd ~` .

Delete files with the command `rm` as shown bellow. Exit tty2  by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, and re-login. This should solve desktop problem when you relogin, since those files will be recreated with new configuration.

```
rm -rf .compiz .config .gconf .gnome .gnome2 .kde .gvfs .local
```

Comment: Terminal is also not visible after logging...

Comment: Nothing comes after logging except wallpaper of ubuntu

Comment: press ALT+F2 this will open similar to run windows type gnome-terminal

Comment: No its not opening...actually nothing works except Ctrl+Alt+F1..for tty1  BLANK Ubuntu wallpaper appears .key pressing shows nothing....

Comment: Then you can use this terminal press Ctrl+Alt+F1 then run the above commands

Comment: I ran above commands ..cd ~ does nothing... My command prompt is like myname@ubuntu$:    so I guess I was already in my home folder isn't? Then I ran rm -rf whole command what you suggested.  Then I press Ctrl+Alt+F7 again I directly landed into blank wallpaper of Ubuntu...or there is another way of logging after running above commands

Comment: you have to delete hidden directories and files then relogin in GUI then configuration files will be recreated in your home folder they will be hidden

Comment: Shall I run rm -fr/home/myuser/.* to delete hidden files? Or Is  there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: i suggest not to use .* this will delete every thing

Comment: OK..but I try to use rm -fr/home/myuser to delete hidden file and its saying unrecognized option -fr/home/myuser

Comment: I am able to view everything after logging...thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

From the login screen you can select different windows managers. Try different windows managers till you get one that works.

Also, you can install windows managers at the command line. For example
    sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
    sudo apt-get install gdm
    ...

**Nuke and pave** is always an option. Reinstall Ubuntu using the "partition it manually" option and make sure you don't format the linux partition (don't format anything). There's always a little risk when doing this but you should be able to have a working dual boot again without trouble.

Make sure to mount your windows partion somewhere (/windows) so that grub knows you have a dual boot situation.

Comment: I tried with gdm last time then Ubuntu splash screen appears with dots...No logging screen appears ...it sticks at splash screen

Comment: Well,I have Ubuntu with windows 7.Will reinstall it work?

Comment: Sure, just be careful where you nuke.

Comment: @JaredRosenberg could you merge your two answers ? lets keep the answers section nice and clean here